# How to auto refresh page after choosing in picklist

Tags: visualforce

How can i make a page to auto refresh after choosing in a picklist and updating the other fields based on the choice made? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After selecting any value are you calling any action function or something?

Comment: use `onchange` event on `apex:selectList` to trigger an actionFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you don't want to refresh the whole page, but rerender its content.

If this is your case, then you can use the `actionSupport` tag:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!field_that_will_receive_the_value}" size="1" id="mylist">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!possible_values_for_that_field}"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="maindiv"></apex:actionSupport>
</apex:selectList>
```

As you can see, the tag will refresh the contents of a section that is identified by "maindiv". You can specify an id to the `apex:body` tag and tell the support tag to rerender it.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here. If you are updating the variables using `actionFunction` you can easily use `oncomplete` to call a javascript function to refresh your page:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="..."
                     action="..."
                     reRender="..."
                     oncomplete="location.reload();" />
```